# Order results by smallest absolute difference from input

Tags: elasticsearch

Can elasticsearch find the closest number to an input?

Example: I have apartments with 1, 2, 5, 6 and 10 rooms. I want a search for apartments with 5 rooms to order results by absolute difference (e.g. |6-5| = 1, |2-5| = 3 etc)

What I want to see: 5, 6, 2, 1, 10.

```
GET appartaments/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":[
        {
          "match":{
            "properties.id":1
          }
        },
        {
          "match":{
            "properties.value":"5"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the ordering? Why 5,6,2,1,10 ?

Comment: The distance. 5-5=0, 6-5=1, 2-5 = |-3|, 1-5 = |-4|, 10-5 = 5

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve what you want using [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#script-based-sorting):

```
GET appartaments/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "Math.abs(params.value - Integer.parseInt(doc['properties.value.keyword'].value))",
        "params": {
          "value": 5
        }
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "properties.id": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Results =>

```
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "appartaments",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "value" : "5"
          }
        },
        "sort" : [
          0.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "appartaments",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "value" : "6"
          }
        },
        "sort" : [
          1.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "appartaments",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "value" : "2"
          }
        },
        "sort" : [
          3.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "appartaments",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "value" : "1"
          }
        },
        "sort" : [
          4.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "appartaments",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "10",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "value" : "10"
          }
        },
        "sort" : [
          5.0
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, I have many properties for apartments. Like rooms, floors, number of WC, etc ...
They have IDs (like in the example, properties.id). I want to search for the most suitable apartment based on my query. I want to know the score.
This is my true task. What should I do? Can you help me with it?

Comment: Fair enough, but it would have been nice to know ALL the important requirements (namely the importance of the score) right from the start :-/

Comment: So, I have ~50 items in my index. Every item has only ID (_id), priority, and 'properties' (array like `[{id:1, value: "5"}, {id: 2, value: "1"}, {id:3, value: "New York"}]`, where id - ID of property, every property has a name in MySQL. like "rooms", "WC", "location"). Properties can be of different types (string, number, bool, list, array). Priority is a parameter for the last sorting. I want to search items by all properties. Like I input 3 rooms, 2 WC, location Amsterdam, and 2 floors. I want to see the most suitable item for me, I want to see the score.
Thank you!